# Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst on OpenSuSe 11.3

Tags: linux, kernel, grub

I compiled the latest kernel, and the **menu.lst** is updated as follows.
My aim is to keep the other kernel around, so that if the new one fails we can still boot from the other one.

Is this the correct way to achieve that?

```
# Modified by YaST2. Last modification on Thu Jan 19 17:10:38 IST 2012
# THIS FILE WILL BE PARTIALLY OVERWRITTEN by perl-Bootloader
# Configure custom boot parameters for updated kernels in /etc/sysconfig/bootloader

default 2
timeout 8
##YaST - generic_mbr
gfxmenu (hd0,1)/boot/message
##YaST - activate

###Don't change this comment - YaST2 identifier: Original name: linux###
title Desktop -- openSUSE 11.3 - 3.2.1-12
    kernel (hd0,1)/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.1-12-desktop root=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3250310AS_6RYNQEXY-part2 resume=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3250310AS_6RYNQEXY-part1 splash=silent quiet showopts vga=0x31a

###Don't change this comment - YaST2 identifier: Original name: failsafe###
title Failsafe -- openSUSE 11.3 - 3.2.1-12
    kernel (hd0,1)/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.1-12-desktop root=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3250310AS_6RYNQEXY-part2 showopts apm=off noresume edd=off powersaved=off nohz=off highres=off processor.max_cstate=1 nomodeset x11failsafe vga=0x31a


###Don't change this comment - YaST2 identifier: Original name: linux###
title Desktop -- openSUSE 11.3 - 2.6.34-12
    root (hd0,1)
    kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.34-12-desktop root=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3250310AS_6RYNQEXY-part2 resume=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3250310AS_6RYNQEXY-part1 splash=silent quiet showopts vga=0x31a
    initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.34-12-desktop


###Don't change this comment - YaST2 identifier: Original name: failsafe###
title Failsafe -- openSUSE 11.3 - 2.6.34-12
    root (hd0,1)
    kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.34-12-desktop root=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3250310AS_6RYNQEXY-part2 showopts apm=off noresume edd=off powersaved=off nohz=off highres=off processor.max_cstate=1 nomodeset x11failsafe vga=0x31a
    initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.34-12-desktop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using grub1, Mine looks like this:

```
# (0) Arch Linux
title  Arch Linux
root   (hd0,0)
kernel /vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda3 resume=/dev/sda2 ro loglevel=3
initrd /initramfs-linux.img

# (1) Arch Linux backup
title  Arch Linux backup
root   (hd0,0)
kernel /vmlinuz-linux-backup root=/dev/sda3 resume=/dev/sda2 ro loglevel=3
initrd /initramfs-linux-backup.img

# (2) Arch Linux FB
title  Arch Linux Fallback
root   (hd0,0)
kernel /vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda3 ro quiet  
initrd /initramfs-linux-fallback.img
```

Also, yesterday I built kernel and did mkinitcpio -p linux-new. The wireless didn't work, So, I reverted it back to old version.

Comment: why is `root   (hd0,0)` on yours and `root   (hd0,1)` on mine? I didn't touch anything there

Comment: the root for the OS. For me it is on the 1st disk and the first partition so I will put the following
(hd0,0). for you it is on the first disk and second partition.

Comment: so, in my menu.lst, will the previous kernel boot if the new one fails? is it written properly?

Comment: You seem to be missing initrd(initial ram disk) in your new kernel. It doesn't matter if the new one doesn't work. The new kernels initially will have few problems loading user modules. But, you will have options in the boot menu to load the old kernel.

Comment: add this to the new kernel at the third line
--> initrd /boot/initrd-3.2.1-12-desktop. 
This is assuming that the initrd is present in that location.

Comment: `add this to the new kernel at the third line --> initrd /boot/initrd-3.2.1-12-desktop` This did the trick. Thanks. Add this to your answer, and I'll select it.

Comment: and what is `mkinitcpio -p linux-new`?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio
- script used to create an initial ramdisk environment.

Comment: @srikanthradix: initrd isn't need to boot the kernel. In fact it makes the boot slow. I don't use it either.

Comment: `add this to the new kernel at the third line --> initrd /boot/initrd-3.2.1-12-desktop` This did the trick. Will you kindly add this to your answer to make it complete, and I'll select it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my menu.1st

```
default 1
timeout 8
gfxmenu (hd1,4)/message

###Don't change this comment - YaST2 identifier: Original name: linux###
title Zen-Kernel - 3.0.3-zen
root (hd1,4)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.3-zen rw root=/dev/sda7 rw resume=/dev/sda6 
showopts quiet fastboot raid=noautodetect radeon.modeset=1    
radeon.lowpower=1 radeon.dynpm=1 video=1440x900 acpi_osi="Linux"
pcie_aspm=force thermal.act=90 acpi.power_nocheck=1 init=/sbin/sysvinit 
nohz=off
```